# Live update product category cart item count without reloading in Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I created a shortcode that counts the quantity of products belonging to the '72' product category, that are added to the cart.

I am using the custom conditional function has_product_category() from this answer thread: 
[Set item quantity to multiples of “x” for products in a specific category in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612495/set-item-quantity-to-multiples-of-x-for-products-in-a-specific-category-in-woo/52612956#52612956)

Here is my code:

```
function cat_cart_count_bottiglie() {
    $bottiglie = 0; 

    // Iterating through each cart item
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_product_category( $cart_item['product_id'], $category_ids = array( 72 ) ) ) {
            $bottiglie += $cart_item['quantity'];
                }
    }
    return $bottiglie;
}
add_shortcode('bottiglie', 'cat_cart_count_bottiglie');
```

The code works correctly.

But this shortcode count get updated only when the page is refreshed after add to cart and doesn't work for Ajax add to cart or when removing items or changing items quantity in cart page.

Is there a way to get the update instantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will Ajax refresh your shortcode custom product category "72" item count:

```
// Custom conditional function that checks also for parent product category terms
function has_product_category( $product_id, $category_ids, $taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) {
    $term_ids = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through the current product category terms to get only parent main category term
    foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy ) as $term ){
        if( $term->parent > 0 ){
            $term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category
            $term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
        } else {
            $term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
        }
    }
    return array_intersect( $category_ids, array_unique($term_ids) );
}

// Custom function that count cart items remaining to a product_category
function get_bottiglie_count( $term_ids ){
    $count = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through each cart item
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_product_category( $cart_item['product_id'], $term_ids ) ) {
            $count += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }

    return $count;
}

// Ajax refressing count
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'refresh_bottiglie_count', 50, 1 );
function refresh_bottiglie_count( $fragments ){

    $fragments['#bottiglie-count'] = do_shortcode( "[bottiglie]" );

    return $fragments;
}

// Shortcode that display the count cart items remaining to a product_category
add_shortcode('bottiglie', 'shortcode_bottiglie_count');
function shortcode_bottiglie_count( $atts ) {
    return '<span id="bottiglie-count">' . get_bottiglie_count( array(72) ) . '</span>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I entered the same shortcode also in the mobile menu.
Just do not update when I change the quantities in the cart or add a new product.

There's a way?

Comment: @Vdgaetano I think that your mobile menu is somehow stopping the process and nobody can really answer this kind of question as it's something particular to your theme (as this kind of behavior is different from one theme to another). Some plugins can also make some issues like.

Answer (score 0):

You will be needing a javascript to run a live changes to DOM, but wordpress shortcodes don't work with ajax (I think, correct me if I'm wrong). But yeah, basically you need ajax to fetch the shortcode again or manually change the DOM after clicking add to cart.