# Do not redirect to checkout if there is an "error" notice in the Woocommerce cart

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, checkout, notice

I created a feature that adds an error message to the cart to prevent you from proceeding to checkout:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'wc_check_cart_qty' );
function wc_check_cart_qty() {

    // only for custom user role 'acquisto_a_bancali'
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( ! in_array( 'acquisto_a_bancali', $current_user->roles ) ) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_product_category( $cart_item['product_id'], $category_ids = array( 1104 ) ) ) {
            $qty += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }

    if ( $qty < 5 ) {
        wc_add_notice( __("You must buy at least 5 products", "woocommerce" ), 'error' );
    }

}
```

Before I entered the function [Live update product category cart item count without reloading in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52754823/live-update-product-category-cart-item-count-without-reloading-in-woocommerce):

```
function has_product_category( $product_id, $category_ids, $taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) {
    $term_ids = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through the current product category terms to get only parent main category term
    foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy ) as $term ){
        if( $term->parent > 0 ){
            $term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category
            $term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
        } else {
            $term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
        }
    }
    return array_intersect( $category_ids, array_unique($term_ids) );
}
```

If the error is displayed in the cart and I go to the Checkout, I should only see the message: "**There are some issues with the items in your cart. Please go back to the cart page and resolve these issues before checking out**", instead I see the form to complete the order.

Why?

Comment: Could you show your complete hooked function code please, as nobody can guess what is wrong with the provided information… Also if your code is based on an existing thread, please add the link in your question.

Comment: In all the functions `wc_add_notice()` with notice type `'error'` is NEVER redirected to the template **wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/cart-errors.php**

Answer (score 0):

I just UNDO my last activity
Error appear when I add new coupon
I don't really know what's the connection why there is an error when I add new coupon.

I hope this can help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).